# Compress a folder consistently

Tags: compression, backup, consistency

I need to compress and copy a large folder for backup purposes.
The folder contains website data which is constantly changing.
To my understanding, when I start the compression process, files can change while the compression is running. Therefore the backup could contain an inconsistent state with files of different version states.

How would I go about this issue. I know there is the possibility of snapshotting the whole drive, mounting the snapshot on another device and execute the compression there. However, is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: If they're constantly changing, what's the point of having a backup in the first place?

Comment: It would be nice to turn back to a state a couple of days ago instead of loosing everything.